# Ruby on Rails query string with special chars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I am having code as follows in my rest_api controller which calls api method using active resource...

@getResponse = api.get(:response, :apiKey => "GKIN1DOM00JXI66LFH5A", :userId => "111-693282-81705419", :token =>"u:sdhfgjsT:sdfgsjdf")

==========================================================================================
In above code when resource url is hit, it converts "**:**" to "%3A" due to which api fails to get the token and returns error as 401 (resource url hit - http://my-api/api/response.josn?apikey=hdsfjdf&token=u**%3A** sdhfgjsT**%3A** sdfgsjdf where is sould be http://my-api/api/response.josn?apikey=hdsfjdf&token=u **:** sdhfgjsT **:** sdfgsjdf)

Please help, to stop escaping my query string params

Comment: can you please show your controller file

Comment: Can you please debug your controller and add the token value (params[:token]) that you are getting in there ?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution that comes to my mind is: "string".html_safe

Comment: @daekrist `require "uri"

class ApiController < ApplicationController
  
   def show
 
     params[:token] = "u:KTDF1B2J72V2KEQJNSSH:b38114ffcef9cbaedc0de8d775584f9b"
    
     @getResponse = api.get(:response, :apiKey => "GKIN1DOM00JXI66LFH5A", :userId => "111-693282-81705419", :token =>"u:sdhfgjsT:sdfgsjdf")
  
end
end`

Comment: I think the problem is inside your response controller.

Comment: When I use `@getResponse = api.get(:response, :apiKey => "GKIN1DOM00JXI66LFH5A", :userId => "111-693282-81705419", :token =>"u:sdhfgjsT:sdfgsjdf")` and I check log for what API is hit, I get url hit as follow
GET http://my-api/api/response.josn?apiKey=GKIN
1DOM00JXI66LFH5A&token=u%3AsdhfgjsT%3Asdfgsjdf&userId=111-693282-81705419

Comment: Escaping strings for get requests is normal, what is not normal, however, is not unescaping them back in controllers.